# How to kill queries on SQL Server when CPU is 100%

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today I have launched a profiler on sql server, CPU went at 100% and I couldn't connect to the database to kill the query.

Is there a management console? How can I use it to kill a query / process?

Comment: "Couldn't connect" as in you couldn't run any queries, or could you not even get it to show up in your object explorer?

Comment: You can kill the SQL Server service and restart it. Be warned though, anyone else that is connected/actively using the database will lose any uncommitted transactions.

Comment: Use SSMS [Activity Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx) to kill the connections.

Comment: @M.Ali, that was my thought too, but he has to be able to connect to the database first to run it

Comment: Activity monitor will not work when there is heavy traffic.  Use sp_who2 or usp_who2 from my website that saves the data to a tempdb table for searching.

Comment: You can use KILL { session ID | UOW } to kill blocked queries.

Comment: It was possible to connect only in remote desktop

Comment: @TTeeple: it's a db of production. Every minute down costs a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068(v=sql.105).aspx

The dedicated administrator connection runs on a separate thread.  You might be able to get using this back door.

Unless you enabled the remote part of the DAC, you will have to Remote Desktop onto the server (MSTSC).

Here are instructions on how to enable remote DAC connections.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1801/enable-sql-server-2008-dedicated-administrator-connection/

If you get in, use sp_who2 to see if there is blocking/deadlock.  Kill the processes that have the lease amount of CPU/IO otherwise the rollback might not be pretty.